# Aggregate results based on where clause using SQLite

Tags: sql, grouping, where-clause

I have a query that counts records based on various criteria, but I would like to split the results into two grouped fields based on said criteria.  Is there a way to do this inside the query - or is it necessary to have two queries?

```
select count(PT_TASK_ASSAY_DISP) as 'Count' from vbasedata v
where 
    v.PT_TASK_ASSAY_DISP like 'SS%' or
    (v.PT_TASK_ASSAY_DISP like 'IP%' and
    v.PT_TASK_ASSAY_DISP not like 'IP CUT' and
    v.PT_TASK_ASSAY_DISP not like 'IP NEG');
```

I'm trying to group by IP and SS to get a total count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure what you want. But if you want one count per 'SS%' and one for 'IP%'. Then maybe something like this:

```
select 
    SUM(CASE WHEN PT_TASK_ASSAY_DISP LIKE 'SS%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as SSCount,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PT_TASK_ASSAY_DISP LIKE 'IP%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as IPCount 
from vbasedata v
where 
    v.PT_TASK_ASSAY_DISP like 'SS%' or
    (v.PT_TASK_ASSAY_DISP like 'IP%' and
    v.PT_TASK_ASSAY_DISP not like 'IP CUT' and
    v.PT_TASK_ASSAY_DISP not like 'IP NEG');
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks much!  I wasn't sure if it was necessary to have a 'TASK_ASSAY' field to group the SS and IP records.